# SSMS 18.1 Azure AD Connection Options Popup

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssms

Just installed new SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) 18.1 GA build. When trying to connect to a Azure SQL instance using Active Directory Universal with MFA Support. After I authenticate using Azure AD, I immediately get a pop up saying "Connection Options" "Azure Active Directory". It asks for an Application ID and Redirect URL and link to Azure Application Registrations.

Screen shot - https://twitter.com/ecpdata/status/1139282704254537730/photo/1

I didn't have these issues in 18 and just tried in 17.9 and don't have the same pop up.

I can cancel out of pop up after a dozen times or so and finally get to the server, just time consuming every time.

Comment: So, what's the question you want to ask?

Comment: Is it a bug in 18.1 or what is expected for Application ID and URL?

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please mark it as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Was able to determine the issue is with a plugin that I use within SSMS that isn't compatible with MFA login type. The plugin developer is aware and working on, the issue is not with SSMS itself.

Comment: Which plugin gave you trouble? I'm running into the same problems right now.

Comment: Ran into this myself, and it was a couple of plugins by ApexSQL.

Comment: Superb thanks! ApexSQL Refactor was causing the issue for me. @ECPdata you should accept your own answer as the right one. You'll get points for it!

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue with ssms 18.2. Problem was solved after uninstalling apex SQLRefactor plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem as other with Apex SQLRefactor, but after updating to the latest version, it seems to have been fixed. This is as of April 2020
[image]